# Hiding first node of tree, or creating a tree with 2 start nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

i have the following code,

```
\[\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=50mm,sibling distance=22mm,every node/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=4pt}]
    \node {}
    child [draw=none,grow=left]{
        child{node{$\frac{4}{3}(1.571583165)-\frac{1}{3}(1.859140914)=1.475730582$}edge from parent[draw=none]
            child{node{$1.859140914$}}
            child{node{$1.571583165$}}
        }
        child{node{$\frac{4}{3}(1.490678862)-\frac{1}{3}(1.571583165)=1.463710761$}edge from parent[draw=none] 
            child{node{$1.571583165$}}
            child{node{$1.490678862$}}
        }};
    \end{tikzpicture}\]
```

which produces the following:

[image]

i want to hide the first node, or if there's a way to start a tree with 2 nodes would be nice too, any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Please always post complete minimal code we can compile. But why are you putting the picture in a display maths environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=50mm,sibling distance=22mm,every node/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=4pt}]
  \node [draw=none] {}
  child [draw=none,grow=left]{
    child{node{$\frac{4}{3}(1.571583165)-\frac{1}{3}(1.859140914)=1.475730582$}edge from parent[draw=none]
      child{node{$1.859140914$}}
      child{node{$1.571583165$}}
    }
    child{node{$\frac{4}{3}(1.490678862)-\frac{1}{3}(1.571583165)=1.463710761$}edge from parent[draw=none]
      child{node{$1.571583165$}}
      child{node{$1.490678862$}}
    }edge from parent[draw=none]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree]